# The float left isn't working with a specific icon

Tags: html, css

[image: float left isn't working]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azizul/v7xuw5gb/16/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="card">
        <!-- plane icon img -->
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P0v6.png" alt="plane" class="card__icon">
        <div class="card__body">
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat dolore eaque veniam architecto. Impedit expedita facilis error nostrum harum cumque, iste aspernatur</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="card">
        <!-- game-pad icon img -->
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgWTv.png" alt="plane" class="card__icon">
        <div class="card__body">
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat dolore eaque veniam architecto. Impedit expedita facilis error nostrum harum cumque, iste aspernatur</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="card">
        <!-- plane icon img -->
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P0v6.png" alt="plane" class="card__icon">
        <div class="card__body">
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat dolore eaque veniam architecto. Impedit expedita facilis error nostrum harum cumque, iste aspernatur</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.container{
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.row:before,.row:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.col-6{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.card{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I created the columns using the CSS **float** property. No framework! Everything is working fine but the last column in the row isn't floating left. can anyone explain?

**Interesting Fact:**
I'm using only two icons called [Plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P0v6.png) and [Gamepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgWTv.png). Interestingly when I changed the [Gamepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgWTv.png) icon with the '[Plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P0v6.png)' icon, it fixes the problem! Still can't figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use:

```
float: right;
```

That's what you need.